# Why cant I center text in Android Studio

Tags: android

I am using a Note 3, and I am still learning Android Studio. I can't align text to center.

Link of Android Studio course: https://developer.android.com/codelabs/basic-android-kotlin-compose-add-images?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcourses%2Fpathways%2Fandroid-basics-compose-unit-1-pathway-3%23codelab-https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.android.com%2Fcodelabs%2Fbasic-android-kotlin-compose-add-images#6

File "MainActivity.kt"

```kotlin
package com.example.happybirthday

import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import android.os.Bundle
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Box
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
//import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Row
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.material.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material.Surface
import androidx.compose.material.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.layout.ContentScale
import androidx.compose.ui.res.painterResource
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import com.example.happybirthday.ui.theme.HappyBirthdayTheme

class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            HappyBirthdayTheme {
                // A surface container using the 'background' color from the theme
                Surface(color = MaterialTheme.colors.background) {
                    BirthdayGreetingWithImage("Happy Birthday Sam!", " - from Emma")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun BirthdayGreetingWithText(message: String, from: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Column(modifier = modifier) {
        Text(
            text = message,
            fontSize = 36.sp,
        )
        Text(
            text = from,
            fontSize = 24.sp,
        )
        Column(
            modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
        ) {
            //...
        }
    }
}

@Composable
fun BirthdayGreetingWithImage(message: String, from: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val image = painterResource(R.drawable.androidparty)
    Box {
        Image(
            painter = image,
            contentDescription = null,
            contentScale = ContentScale.Crop
        )
        BirthdayGreetingWithText(message = message, from = from)

    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = false)
@Composable
fun BirthdayCardPreview() {
    HappyBirthdayTheme {
        BirthdayGreetingWithImage("Happy Birthday Sam!", " - from Emma")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your code according to this:

```
@Composable
fun BirthdayGreetingWithText(message: String, from: String, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Column(
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
        horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
    ) {
        Text(
            text = message,
            fontSize = 36.sp,
        )
        Text(
            text = from,
            fontSize = 24.sp,
        )
        ...
    }
}
```

You apply a modifier to a **nested** `Column`, causing it to be applied to its nested content. You need to apply a modifier to the **parent** `Column` for it to apply to the nested text.